# How to get searched word or params in URL

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I'm making my own website and I want to get searched word or params in URL from my website.

For example, if I searched "Nike" from my website, the URL would be turned into http://localhost:3000/searched/Nike. Then I want to get the work "Nike" from the URL. How can I get the word from URL?

Comment: Are you using React or pure Javascript?
If you're using React then you can make your URL as 
<Route path="/searched/:searchTerm" render={ (props) => <UserPage {...props} /> } />
and get the searchTerm as this.props.match.params.searchTerm

Comment: or use `useParams()` hook, if you use function component.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to display its value in an input field:

```
$("#inputId").val($.url.param("keyword"));
```

Or use can use the below steps:-

```
var word = "http://localhost:3000/searched/Nike";
var url = document.location.href;
var regExp = new RegExp(word, 'Nike');

if (regExp.test(url))
    alert("The word " + word + " is in the URL!");
else
    alert("The word " + word + " is NOT in the URL.");
```